# Bennche Spire 1000 - 6 pin connection

Tags: atv

Purchased this used atv and repaired the wiring harness which was already pulled off from the previous owner. Now that I got the harness fixed trying to find where this white 6 pin connector goes. Been looking at the manual and believe I am missing relay or something but cant be sure. Not finding a lot of info on this machine but found this: https://www.partsboss.com/Bennche-Parts/ELECTRICAL_PARTS_SPIRE1000 which doesnt help much.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that connector is used for diagnostics, that's the only information I got from a dealership down in Texas. Seems like none wants to work on these things. I was able to find the cause of my issue on a different wire seen in the first image on the far bottom right (black connector) not making proper contact. That seems to be controlling some of the ignition because now I'm getting spark.